# Undefined Constructor error

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Am trying to implement a system for a car dealer, but when I try to instantiate my `Car` class in a derived class, I get the error message

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The constructor Car(String, int, String, String, double, double) is 
 undefined
```

Here's the parent class Car:

```
package Number3;

public class Car {

private String plateNum;
private int year;
private String make;
private String model;
protected double costPrice;
protected double sellingPrice;

public Car()
{
    plateNum = "";
    year = 1990;
    make = "";
    model = "";
    costPrice = 0.0;
    sellingPrice = 0.0;
}

public Car(String plateNum,int year,String make,String model,double costPrice,double sellingPrice)
{
    this.plateNum = plateNum;
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.costPrice = costPrice;
    this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
}

public double getCostPrice()
{
    return costPrice;
}

public double computeSellPrice()
{
    sellingPrice = costPrice;
    return sellingPrice;
}

public void displayCarDetails()
{
    System.out.println("Plate number: "+plateNum);
    System.out.println("Year: "+year);
    System.out.println("Make: "+make);
    System.out.println("Cost price: "+costPrice);
    System.out.println("Selling price: "+sellingPrice);
}

}
```

and the subclass `newCar`:

```
package Number3;

public class newCar extends Car{

private double tax;

public newCar(String plateNum,int year, String make, double costPrice, double sellingPrice, double tax)
{
    super(plateNum,year,make,costPrice,sellingPrice); //where the error is found
    this.tax = (25/100);
}

public double computeSellPrice()
{
    sellingPrice = costPrice + (costPrice * tax);
    return sellingPrice;
}

public void displayCarDetails()
{
    super.displayCarDetails();
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The constructor is indeed not there - you have a small error in your Super() call.

Comment: Your super class constructor expects a model parameter as well. You are not passing it for new car but you do that for the used car.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Can you answer the question please? With examples as it's not clear to me. I haven't yet grasped the concepts of OOP fully.

Comment: I've tried it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of your Car constructor does not match the signature in the derived class.

In your `Car` class, this is the constructor:

```
public Car(String plateNum,int year,
      String make,String model,double costPrice,double sellingPrice) {
        ...
  }
```

It is `String, int, String, String, double, double)`

While in the derived class:

you have:

```
super(plateNum,year,make,costPrice,sellingPrice)
```

Which is `int, int, String, double, double`

Change the arguments in call to `Super` in your `newCar` class to match the constructor of your `Car` class. That is, in your `newCar` class, the line

```
super(plateNum,year,make,costPrice,sellingPrice)
```

should be :

```
super(plateNum, year,
      make, model, costPrice, sellingPrice)
```

Comment: In which derived class is it int? And how to fix it? I can't find it. Actually plateNum was int before i modified it to String.

Comment: Just make sure the constructor in your Car class matches that in any class where you call `super`.

Comment: You are welcome.One more thing, your class name `newCar` should be `NewCar`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Car` class does not have a constructor that takes 5 parameters.

It is defined as

```
public Car(String plateNum,int year,String make,String model,double costPrice,double sellingPrice)
{
 ...
}
```

and you're trying to call it without passing the `model` parameter.

```
super(plateNum,year,make,costPrice,sellingPrice); //where the error is found
```

Comment: This is not true. It does - the parameters do match, however.

Answer (score 1):

Your super/parent class `Car` has a no-argument constructor `public Car() {` and the following 6-parameter constructor which is being called from the sub/child class constructors using the keyword `super`.

```
public Car(String plateNum,int year,String make,String model,double costPrice,double sellingPrice)
```

Notice, that it expects `String model` as its fourth parameter but your `public newCar()` constructor is passing it only five parameters. The parameter `model` is missing.

```
public newCar(String plateNum,int year, String make, double costPrice, double sellingPrice, double tax)
{
    super(plateNum,year,make,costPrice,sellingPrice); // model MISSING!
```

So, to fix it, either modify the constructor to accept `model` as well (just like in your `usedCar()` constructor) or pass `null` to the super class constructor as

```
super(plateNum,year,make,null,costPrice,sellingPrice); // model = null
```